# What is this block of code and how does it affect the Hibernate entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, constructor, entity

What does the following code do in the class below?

```
public Employee() {
}
```

Does it have any effect on the Hibernate entity? If so, what effect?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="age")
    private Integer age;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(Integer id, String name, Integer age) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simply a no-arg [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), in other word a constructor that takes no input.

The [JPA specification states](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) that:

> The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may have other constructors as well. The no-arg constructor must be public or protected.

In other words, JPA relies on a no-args constructor being present. The way it works under the hood is that Hibernate creates your entities by using their default constructors, then sets values via their setter methods, or even bypasses the setters, depending on how you configure it.

Since the constructor `Employee(Integer id, String name, Integer age)` has been added to the class, the default no-arg constructor is not included:

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.

Given this a no-arg constructor must be explicitly added, as in your `Employee` class, for JPA (which Hibernate implements) to work.

Comment: so it means that it is required to be added in the code ?

Comment: @ElarCampañano Yes, since you have a constructor with arguments, the default no-arg constructor will be omitted, as per the quote. Hence, you need to implement the no-arg constructor.